# Extjs Combo - Why combo is loading while I have not created form include combo

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I define a window include a form and some field and combo box. Example like

```
    Ext.define('Ext.example.ABC', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',   
        items:{
            xtype:'form',
            items:[
            {
            xtype: 'combo',
            id: 'example',
            name: 'ax',
            triggerAction:  'all',
            forceSelection: true,
            editable:       false,
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel:     'example',
            mode: 'remote',
            displayField:'name',
            valueField: 'id',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields: [
                                {name: 'id'},
                                {name: 'name'}
                            ],
                            autoLoad: true,
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                url: 'example.php',
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    root: 'rows'
                                }
                            }
                }
            })
            }]
         }
         ,load: function(a) {
              // do some thing
         }
});
```

And I have a button in a **grid panel**

```
tbar:[
        {    
            text:'create',
            handler:function(){
                         var x = new Ext.example.ABC();
                 x.load(0);

            }
        }
```

But Why when i just start gridpanel then combo also load while I have not click button **create**.

 I have many combo box and that make my grid panel load slowly :(

 How can i fix that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need set `autoLoad: false` config option for your combobox's `store`.

---

In relation to your comments - I've created an example. You can check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvxfC/).
It was created on ExtJs 3.4, but I think for 4.x it will be not very different.

```
var arrTestData = [
    ['AL', 'Alabama', 'The Heart of Dixie'],
    ['AK', 'Alaska', 'The Land of the Midnight Sun'],
    ['AZ', 'Arizona', 'The Grand Canyon State'],
    ['AR', 'Arkansas', 'The Natural State'],
    ['CA', 'California', 'The Golden State']
];

var combosCount = 5;
var arrItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < combosCount; i++) {
    var comboId = Ext.id();

    // simple array store
    var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        parentCombo: comboId,
        fields: ['abbr', 'state', 'nick'],
        data : []
    });

    store.on('load', function() {
        var combo = Ext.getCmp(this.parentCombo);
        combo.setValue(combo.defaultValue);
    });

    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        id: comboId,
        fieldLabel: 'Combobox #' + (i + 1),
        store: store,
        displayField:'state',
        valueField:'abbr',
        typeAhead: true,
        mode: 'local',
        forceSelection: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'Select a state...',
        defaultValue: arrTestData[i][0],
        selectOnFocus:true
    });
    arrItems.push(combo);
}

var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
    items: arrItems,
    renderTo: 'combos-container'
});


new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Do all cool things',
    renderTo: 'combos-btn',
    handler: function() {
        var arrCombos = formPanel.findByType('combo');
        Ext.each(arrCombos, function(combo){
            combo.getStore().loadData(arrTestData);
        });
    }
});
```

So what we do there:
1. For each store we'll save parent combobox id - this is required to identify related combobox.
2. For each combobox we save own parameter - defaultValue. This is the value we want set as default after store will be loaded.
3. Listen for 'load' event and set default value for the combo.

I hope this is what you was waiting for :)

Comment: But i want set a default value If set autoLoad: false then nothing :(

Comment: You can set default value for the combobox by using `value` config option. At that time store must have all required data. I think you need to run manually store loading and when it will receive data -> set value to the combo.

Comment: Do u have any example? b/c i have many combo box (about 5) :(

Comment: I think your edit so cool but i using url to get data. Can u make a dialog wait for all combo load done? . Thanks so much

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. We load data to the comboboxes separately. E.g. you can use `autoload` + real url. For each store we listen for `load` event and this means that we'll run our code only when data will be received. If you want don't automatically load comboboxes -> set `autoLoad` to `false` for each store of the comboboes. And run `store.reload()` when you need.

Comment: So have you tried what I've wrote? Please mark my answer as resolved if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Have `autoLoad:false` and load your store manually for default values.
When you really want to load the store, you can do

```
store.load()
```

which will load your store for default values.

Comment: But Have anyway to catch when all my store (combo) loading done? I have many combo (some combo maybe dynamic) :(

Comment: Refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003605/how-to-wait-until-all-stores-are-loaded-in-extjs)